# Laravel 4 - Get URI of Named Route

Tags: laravel-4, routes

Anyone know how to get the uri of a named route? Something like this:

```
$sourceUri = Route::getNamedRoute('nameOfMyRoute')->getPath(); //this doesn't work of course
```

The reason I want this is to determine if the current route requested by the client is the same as a given named route like this:

```
$targetUri = Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath(); //this DOES work
return sourceUri === targetUri;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one probably will work:

```
Route::getRoutes()->getByName('name.of.your.route')->getUri();
```

Comment: Beautiful. This worked: `Route::getRoutes()->getbyName('routeName')->getUri()`. Not familiar with the `dd` function though.

Comment: dd is a Laravel helper for var_dump($stuff); die;

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$url = route('routeName', $params);
```

Comment: `route('routeName')` returns the entire url (i.e. `http://subdomain.example.com/uri`). I only want the uri the way that `getPath()` or `uri()` do.